# Displaying login error messages from passport.js on ejs

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js

my ignorance is not letting me display login error messages on passport.js . I'd like to pass to my ejs login page the `message`  defined on `passport.use` , but I get lost in the flow, for I'm not sure who is handling the done function, but I understand that somehow it is connected to the `passport.authenticate`.

It seems that `failureRedirect` is calling res.render under the hood, and it would be nice to be able to pass to it the message from the passport.use

I tried unsuccessfully to set up up the Flash Messages, but I'd like to avoid that if it is possible. Here's part of the code, it is mainly boilerplate

```
passport.use(
    new LocalStrategy((username, password, done) => {
        User.findOne({ username: username }, (err, user) => {
            if (err) {
                return done(err);
            };
            if (!user) {
                console.log("Incorrect username");
                return done(null, false, { message: "Incorrect username" });
            }
            bcrypt.compare(password, user.password, (err, res) => {
                if (res) {
                    // passwords match! log user in
                    console.log("Si pudiste logearte!!");
                    return done(null, user)
                } else {
                    // passwords do not match!
                    console.log("Incorrect password");
                    return done(null, false, { message: "Incorrect password" })
                }
            })
        });
    })
);
```

```
router.post(
    "/log-in",
    passport.authenticate("local", {
        failureFlash: false,
        successRedirect: "/",
        failureRedirect: "/log-in"

    })
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `connect-flash` to display messages.

```
npm install connect-flash
```

Change `failureFlash` to true. And the error will be available in views as `messages.error`

```
...

var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var flash = require('connect-flash');
var app = express();

...

app.use(session({cookie: { maxAge: 60000 }}));
app.use(flash());

...
router.post(
    "/log-in",
    passport.authenticate("local", {
        failureFlash: true,
        successRedirect: "/",
        failureRedirect: "/log-in"

    })
);
```

Comment: Well, that is not working for me, messages (or message) is not defined.